# Checking null event horizon for a metric

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, metric-tensor

I know that an event Horizon is a null hypersurface defining the boundary of the black hole region of spacetime. The first question is should all the black holes in general relativity have a null event horizon? And my second question is, If we have a metric, is having a null event horizon a condition for this metric to be a solution to Einstein's equations? How can one calculate this condition (whether your metric has a null event horizon or not?). I want to know its calculations.

Comment: A complete answer to your question would be huge. You might sample such resources as Hawking and Ellis https://www.amazon.com/Structure-Space-Time-Cambridge-Monographs-Mathematical/dp/0521099064/   Bring your maths ability, you will need it.

Comment: Thank you! I will check that resource.